# How get stream from flash player

Tags: flash, stream, rtmp

I have a problem.

I must have a stream url from this URL: http://stimotion.pl/galeria-kamer-online?catid=krosno&slg=krosno_rondo. I tried to look in the source code, but I can't see any things to e.g  play this video in VLC. In [rondo.js](http://stimotion.pl/flow/krosno/rondo.js) file I see rtmp but it doesn't work.

Can anyone to help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this one using wireshark.

This video pretty much sums up how to do that :

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PuUnQCS7DQ
```

If you follow the video you come up with this command :

```
rtmpdump -v -r "rtmp://80.48.180.7/krosno/krosno3" | vlc -
```